How to achieve compliance between Graphql in Virtuoso and Python graphql-db-api
Recent additions of GraphQL views to Open Link Virtuoso motivated to make one more attempt of using data from Virtuoso in Apache Superset.
For that purpose, Python lib graphql-db-api may be used. It provides needed integration with SQLAlchemy and Superset works well with GraphQL endpoints used in the graphql-db-api examples.
However attempts at using that library to retrieve data from Virtuoso GraphQL endpoints did not give positive results.
Investigation shows that graphql-db-api expects an explicit top-level type of NON_NULL kind in the GraphQL schema, but Virtuoso does not use such top-level type in its own GraphQL schema.
For example, GraphQL endpoint graphql://pet-library.moonhighway.com
has the following fragment of schema:
    {
        "data": {
            "__schema": {
                "queryType": {
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "allPets",
                            "type": {
                                "name": null,
                                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                                "ofType": {
                                    "name": null,
                                    "kind": "LIST",
                                    "ofType": {
                                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                                        "name": null,
                                        "ofType": {
                                            "name": "Pet"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },

The field allPets has a top-level type of kind NON_NULL and only after that the type of kind LIST follows.
While a Virtuoso-hosted GraphQL endpoint returns the following schema:
{
    "data": {
        "__schema": {
            "queryType": {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "ConceptSchemes",
                        "type": {
                            "name": null,
                            "kind": "LIST",
                            "ofType": {
                                "name": "ConceptScheme",
                                "kind": "OBJECT",
                                "ofType": null
                            }
                        }
                    }

Here the field ConceptSchemes has only a type of kind LIST.
Is it possible to configure GraphQL views in Virtuoso with additional level of the top-level type with NON_NULL kind?

It looks like you're trying RDF linked data views via GraphQL bridge and talking about a GraphQL introspection query result used by the Python application/driver.
Thus you are doing TTLP(GQL_CREATE_TYPE_SCHEMA ('rdf view generated schema graph IRI')) as described here.
The above statement imports a Turtle document describing the introspection graph for the RDF view; therefore it contains statements for Query type,
like this —
:Query :fields [ :name "Products" ; :type [ :kind "LIST" ; :ofType ns0:Products ] ] .
If you want to make Products lists non-null, you have to save the result from GQL_CREATE_TYPE_SCHEMA(), for example via string_to_file() function, and then modify the above statement in the Turtle document to —
:Query :fields [ :name "Products" ; :type  [ :kind "NON_NULL"; :ofType  [  :kind "LIST" ; :ofType ns0:Products ] ] ] .
— or you could use your own SDL like this —
type Product {
  ProductId: ID!
  ProductName: String!
  # etc.
}

type Query {
  Products: [Product!]!
}

— and make a Turtle document for the introspection graph via GQL_GENERATE_INTRO([sdl document]).
Once triples declared for this particular kind of array are not nullable, you should import and register into the Graphql bridge introspection graph.

Thank a lot for the solution. The first variant with manual modification of TTL was applied successfully. Now Apache Superset can use data from Virtuoso.

Would it be possible to read more about details and examples related to Virtuoso RDF Ontology to GraphQL mappings schema (ie Function fieilds) ?

I suggest you start with Introducing Native GraphQL Support in Virtuoso and Usage Guide – Virtuoso GraphQL Views Creation & Management. Further Virtuoso-related questions will be answered most quickly via the OpenLink Community Forum.
